# Site or feed covering current coffee offer

Tags: business

Is there a site or feed which would collect current coffee offer from various roasters especially specialty coffee roasters? I like to try wide range of coffees and so far I'm checking several website-shops to see what is new. Maybe someone is already collecting this information on a single spot.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of a site specifically for that, but definitely hit up Sprudge if you never have. It is certainly the leading site for all coffee information - and it's very easy to scroll through and find new coffee companies that are all doing great things.

http://sprudge.com/